# Path expressions on documents with namespaces

Tags: xquery, basex

I need my query to return the values of the attribute EventType. This is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

-<Report xmlns="VehicleExcelActivityReport" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Name="VehicleExcelActivityReport" xsi:schemaLocation="VehicleExcelActivityReport https://onlineavl2rpt-cl.navmanwireless.com/ReportServer?%2FFLD_99b60f01-620d-4651-a2c4-31d773d80fca%2FVehicleExcelActivityReport&rs%3ACommand=Render&rs%3AFormat=XML&rs%3ASessionID=sklpjpaslys3ujybhjorfabz&rs%3ASnapshot=2020-01-16T01%3A27%3A35&rc%3ASchema=True">


-<OwnerList>


-<Owner_Collection>


-<Owner>


-<Activities>


-<Detail_Collection>

<Detail Longitude="-71,45113" Latitude="-30,42046" Location="Ruta 5 Norte Km (400 - 410), Iv Region, Chile" Channel="" Driver="LUIS LILLO" NumSatellites="11" HDOP="0,8" OnSiteTimeUnits="min" OnSiteTime="0" TripUnit="km" TripDistance="0" SpeedUnit="km/h" Speed="0" EventTime="07:51 a.m." EventDate="14/01/2020" EventType="Ignition On" Registration="GKZJ-97" Vehicle="GKZJ-97"/>

<Detail Longitude="-71,58305" Latitude="-31,23375" Location="Ruta 5 Norte Km (300 - 310), Iv Region, Chile" Channel="" Driver="LUIS LILLO" NumSatellites="7" HDOP="1,2" OnSiteTimeUnits="min" OnSiteTime="0" TripUnit="km" TripDistance="103.300003051758" SpeedUnit="km/h" Speed="0" EventTime="09:19 a.m." EventDate="14/01/2020" EventType="Ignition Off" Registration="GKZJ-97" Vehicle="GKZJ-97"/>


</Detail_Collection>

</Activities>

</Owner>

</Owner_Collection>

</OwnerList>

</Report>
```

This is my code:

```
for $x in /Report/OwnerList/Owner_Collection/Owner/Activities/Detail_Collection/Detail
  return string($x/@EventType)
```

but I get no hits. I have also tried `return data($x/@EventType)` `return ($x/@EventType/string())` and `return ($x/@EventType/data())` but no hits.

I would appreciate so much your help.

Greetings

Comment: Please ensure that the XML document you supply is complete and well-formed; this will help people to answer your question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for more information.

Comment: Thanks @ChristianGrün. The XML document I supply is exactly the report an application gives to me. Please tell me if you see something incorrect in it (I am new in XML). By the way, some xquery tests in other XML documents were successfull: I got the hits I wanted.

Comment: Well, finally I found the thing: there is something about the namespaces...

Comment: It may feel like a marginal issue, but your document, as you pasted it in this question, cannot be parsed without modifications (see the leading dashes right at the beginning).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All nodes of your document are in the `VehicleExcelActivityReport` namespace. Your path can be resolved if you introduce your query with a default element namespace declaration:

```
declare default element namespace 'VehicleExcelActivityReport';
..
```